# Why Am I getting extra messages when sending keystroke to an application?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am sending CTRL+A and CTRL+C to an application ( in order to copy the content obviously ).
For this I wrote some C++ code which seems to be ok.

Indeed I see on spy++ that the messages produced and sent to the application by my code are exactly the same ( expect frepeat value ) than the messages received by the application when CTRL+A and CTRL+C are inputed ,manually on the keyboard... except that with my code, the application receive at the end two extra WM_CHAR messages for 'A' and 'B'.

since I do not send these WM_CHAR messages but only WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP I am slightly puzzled. Incidentally nothing is selected and nothing is copied ( even if selected before )

here is my C++ code:

```
HWND hTargetWindow=(HWND) 0x280908;


LPARAM lparam1 = 0x00000001 | (LPARAM)(0x1D << 16); 
LPARAM lparam2 = 0x00000001 | (LPARAM)(0x1E << 16);  
LPARAM lparam3 = 0x00000001 | (LPARAM)(0x2E << 16); 

LPARAM lparam1_ = lparam1 | (LPARAM)(0x1 << 31); 
LPARAM lparam2_ = lparam2 | (LPARAM)(0x1 << 31); 
LPARAM lparam3_ = lparam3 | (LPARAM)(0x1 << 31); 

PostMessage(hTargetWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, lparam1);
PostMessage(hTargetWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_A, lparam2);


PostMessage(hTargetWindow, WM_KEYUP, VK_CONTROL, lparam1_);
PostMessage(hTargetWindow, WM_KEYUP, VK_A, lparam2_);


PostMessage(hTargetWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, lparam1);
PostMessage(hTargetWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_C, lparam3);

PostMessage(hTargetWindow, WM_KEYUP, VK_C, lparam3_);
PostMessage(hTargetWindow, WM_KEYUP, VK_CONTROL, lparam1_);
```

and here respectively

a) the messages received when CTRL+A CTRL+C are inputed manually
[image]
b) here the messages received when when CTRL+A CTRL+C are sent by my C+ code

[image]

I will put frepeat to 1 for KEYUP events  but I doubt this will change anything so I post the question anyway.

**so why are these two extra messages sent by my code ?**

thanks in advance for any hint.

***added 7:09:05 p.m.(GMT + 2:00):***

the KEYUP and KEYDOWN for CTRL+A are reversed ( CTRL+C sequence is the same )  but this is because I have also tried this to solve the problem.  I have also tried many times the right combination.

this is spy++ when the keydown and keyup dequence is exactly the same , that does not change anything:

[image]

Comment: They are sent by Windows. It's often easier to check for that than keep track of down and up manually. Of course the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276(v=vs.85).aspx) tells you as much. It's due to the application using `TranslateMessage`.

Comment: sorry I don't get this? what do you mean by translatemessage?

Comment: You only faked the messages, you didn't actually change the keyboard state of the thread.  Which still has the CTRL key up.  So the program's TranslateMessage() call sees you typing A and C without the CTRL key being down so generates WM_CHAR messages for them.  You need AttachThreadInput() and SetKeyboardState() to modify the state.  Or use SendInput().

Comment: @KarlZorn, [`TranslateMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955(v=vs.85).aspx) is a part of every "my first window" program.

Comment: @HansPassant they have a button to flag an answer that should have been a comment, but not one for a comment that should have been an answer...

Comment: @chris: TranslateMessage is a part of every "my first window" program.

I know about TranslateMessage, so far what I tried to say is that your  comment makes no sense ( likes many many  comments and answers I saw in that website anyway ) , what do you mean by 'they are sent by windows' ( yes, they are obviously not sent by a magical dwarf )  and 'it's due to the application using translate message' , for me that looks like a randomly generated comment from someone that 1) do not understand the question 2) don't really know any answer 3) try to look smart

Comment: @Hans Passant , no that can't be that because clearly CTRL must be DOWN, then A must be DOWN then A must be UP then CTLR must be UP , try to have CTRL DOWN, CTRL UP , then A DOWN and A UP with manually submitted input and indeed it will send WM_CHAR A. ( well I tried anyway also combinations like CTRL DOWN, A DOWN, CTRL UP, A UP as explained in my addition 7:09:05 p.m.(GMT + 2:00) ) , also invoking the role of TranslateMessage is like saying that the problems can be solved by putting some bits in the right order, eg that doesn't help at all and this is kind of tautology.

Comment: @Hans Passant 'you didn't actually change the keyboard state of the thread. Which still has the CTRL key up'. possibly I don't know, then if the thread don't process CTRL DOWN , why does it process A DOWN obviously? also references to translatemessage are too general, this is like answering 'well this is a problem with windows' ...

Comment: @Hans Passan if the A DOWN event is received and processed by the application then the CTRL DOWN event before should be also received and processed. The point is that the application process CTRL+A sequence as A. Also you said that I only 'fake' key events ... how does the keyboard driver works then? It also 'fake' key events... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing things in the wrong order, doing the `WM_KEYUP` on `VK_A` before you do the `WM_KEYUP` on `VK_CONTROL`. Same for the `C`. Reverse those and it should be fine.

Comment: ok as explained in addition to my post following your answer, I have tried reversed the sequence for 'CTRL+A' to test if that would change anything but if tested first with the same sequence and these extra WM_CHAR are always sent

Answer (score 0):

```
// Send [CTRL-A] to select the entire text in a Notepad window, even if Notepad is out of focus,
// without bringing the Notepad window into focus.
// Works with Notepad, but not with Command Prompt window.
BYTE gucKeybStateCur [256] = {'\0'};
// hwN = Find Notepad HWND
AttachThreadInput (GetWindowThreadProcessId (hwN, NULL), GetCurrentThreadId (), TRUE);
GetKeyboardState ((PBYTE) &gucKeybStateCur);
gucKeybStateCur [VK_CONTROL] |= 0x80;
SetKeyboardState ((LPBYTE) &gucKeybStateCur);
PostMessage (hwN, WM_KEYDOWN, (WPARAM) 0x00000041, (LPARAM) 0x001E0001);
PostMessage (hwN, WM_KEYUP, (WPARAM) 0x00000041, (LPARAM) 0xC01E0001);
GetKeyboardState ((PBYTE) &gucKeybStateCur);
gucKeybStateCur [VK_CONTROL] &= 0x0F;
SetKeyboardState ((LPBYTE) &gucKeybStateCur);
AttachThreadInput (GetWindowThreadProcessId (hwN, NULL), GetCurrentThreadId (), FALSE);

// Send [CTRL-C] to interrupt a batch file running in a Command Prompt window, even if the Command Prompt window is not visible,
// without bringing the Command Prompt window into focus.
// [CTRL-C] will have an effect on the batch file, but not on the Command Prompt  window itself -- in other words,
// [CTRL-C] will not have the same visible effect on a Command Prompt window that isn't running a batch file at the moment
// as bringing a Command Prompt window that isn't running a batch file into focus and pressing [CTRL-C] on the keyboard.
ulong ulProcessId = 0UL;
// hwC = Find Command Prompt window HWND
GetWindowThreadProcessId (hwC, (LPDWORD) &ulProcessId);
AttachConsole ((DWORD) ulProcessId);
SetConsoleCtrlHandler (NULL, TRUE);
GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent (CTRL_C_EVENT, 0UL);
SetConsoleCtrlHandler (NULL, FALSE);
FreeConsole ();
```

Comment: For increased readability, I recommend that you take your comments outside of the code block.